Boy and girl separated, leading different lives, find a way to get back together
The movie starts as an Indian boy and girl meet in her father's restaurant. The father is being extorted by the local mob and when he doesn't pay, they bomb the place. 
The boy and girl become separated. The boy finds a way to get a job in a utopian city so he can gain the ability to find her.
When he does find her, it turns out she had been taken into high-class prostitution.
Determined to rescue her from that life, he spends every waking moment to save her.
Set in a war-destroyed world, the utopian city is shielded from seeing anything outside of the city by a holographic exterior.
I've googled for it 100 times, I just can't find it based on my description, please help.
I saw it sometime after 2009 but, I didn't take note of the date it was created. External scenes from the utopian city made me think it was filmed in India, but it may not have been. None of the actors I recognized from previous British or American films. It was in English though; no subtitles or mouth movements that didn't match what was being said.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

I've described as best I could. As for the movie, I don't even recall a single characters name, I only remember the story line. At 1 point the main character gets told by a senior partner in his company that he's going to a place considered vacation for the elite but, it's really an elaborate whore house, the movie might be a little more that PG13 but, it's barely R rated. The main character then finds out that his girl is in his place and 1 time delivered to his very building where he works, that's when he really gets to work on saving her.

It was made in the last 15 years and resembles Slum Dog Millionaire except for the sci-fi aspect of it being a futuristic Utopian and Distopian society.

Feel free to [edit] any additional details and improvements of the question title into the question.

If I knew more, I wouldn't be asking for help, I just went through 200 movies on Kodi and couldn't find it. I did recall watching it randomly on Canada's W Network. And I'm sure it aired since 2009 but, that wouldn't be indicative of the date it was produced.

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title, though. It's clear you're looking for a movie you can't remember, neither are you the first one ever doing so.
